# current date query not working HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am facing an issue while trying to retrieve the records from database that are before today`s date using hibernate query.

My query is .

```
Query q = getSession().createQuery("FROM News n where n.to_published_date<= 
          current_date order by n.to_published_date desc");
          return q.list();
```

This query is fetching all records from DB, whereas I require records before todays date.

Comment: Before today's date will give you all, doesn't it? You've used `<=`, instead use `<` to skip today's date records.

Comment: didn`t work for me, i want all records before current time 5/27/2017 1:19:11 PM@N00bPr0grammer

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this, as shown below?

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String frmDate = format.parse(current_date);

Query q = getSession().createQuery("FROM News n where n.to_published_date<= :frmDate order by n.to_published_date desc")
                      .setTimestamp("frmDate ", current_date);
return q.list();
```

Setting the `.setTimestamp()` should do the trick in your case! You can change the date format, as per your need - the way you are saving your `Date` object.

Hope this helps!